# Previous row value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to find a way of retrieving a value from the previous row. What I want to do is first sort the rows by Date 1 (earliest first). Then, if Date 2 is later than all previous dates in that column, I want to pull out that row (plus the first initial row). My server does not support the LAG function. I have tried suggestions using CTE, but my server does not seem to recognise that either.

What I want to do is check whether, after sorting by Date 1, if Date_2 for row 2 > Date_2 for row 1, and if so return that row.

Here's an example table. As you can see, the ID is not in the same order as Date 1.

`ID   Date 1      Date 2
1    2000-01-01  2010-01-01
2    2001-08-01  2013-06-01
3    2000-06-01  2011-01-01
4    1999-07-01  2010-12-01
5    2002-02-01  2012-12-01`

So in my example, I want these 3 records to be returned:

`ID   Date_1      Date_2      Previous_max
4    1999-07-01  2010-12-01  NULL
3    2000-06-01  2011-01-01  2010-12-01
2    2001-08-01  2013-06-01  2011-01-01`

ID 1 and 5 are not returned because Date 1 is later and Date 2 is earlier than another row (4 and 2 respectively).

Comment: sql server and oracle support the LAG keyword, which makes this easy and well-performing. The hack you need in MySql is less so, on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a correlated subquery:

```
  select t.*,
         (select max(date_2) from table t2 where t2.date_1 < t.date_1) as prev_max
  from table t
  having prev_max is null or prev_max < date_2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm fairly new to SQL and I don't understand the use of "table t2"? I only have the data in one table (which in this case would be table t). I get a #1064 error when trying to run the code.

Comment: `t2` is a table alias.  It is a way to distinguish the reference to the table in the subquery from the reference in the outer query.  This is a case where table aliases are needed.